# emberjs : What does the ...arguments in this._super(...arguments) signify?

Tags: ember.js

I have just started using ember js and I tripped over this function a lot of times 
Could someone brief about the use of **this._super()** and also explain the importance of **...arguments** 
Thanks

Comment: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/ you have it here explained you just need to scroll a bit :)

Comment: Thank you so much @SedadKosovac :)
That helped

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need this, whenever you are overriding classes/functions (e.g. `didReceiveAttrs` in a component). It makes sure, that important functions of your parent are called that you might not be aware of. 
The `...arguments` parameter is a basic javascript approach to encapsulate a number of (optional) parameters that the super function might need...

Comment: Thank you so much :D
The link given by @Sedad Kosovac also helped to understand the concept